# Running small periodical high-priority background taks on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background-process

App that I am working on is offering a VPN connection, that can run even when the app is not running at all. This service is paid, but also I would like to offer a free trial limited by session length and maximum data transfered.

The problem I've encoutered, is with monitoring the data trasnfered when the app is in background or not runing at all. So far the best solution I've came up with, would be to periodically run small task that checks if the user is still within the data limit and if not, the VPN will be disconnected and notification shown to the user.

Will silent notification get priority every time it will be required? According to this quote from developer.apple.com, they are low-priority which isn't what I need, but I was unable to find anything else.

> Silent notifications are not meant as a way to keep your app awake in the background, nor are they meant for high priority updates. APNs treats silent notifications as low priority and may throttle their delivery altogether if the total number becomes excessive. The actual limits are dynamic and can change based on conditions, but try not to send more than a few notifications per hour.

How can this be done reliably? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a personal VPN connection (i.e. you're just providing a config to the standard system) and you're not in the flow, then this isn't possible. There is intentionally no "I want my program to run all the time" solution. Even if you come up with one, Apple will probably shut you down.

If you're writing an MDM/supervised VPN connection (i.e. you're providing a `...Flow` object of your own), then you're already running all the time and you can just control it as you want. I'm assuming you have the former or you wouldn't be asking.

I believe you're doing this backwards. Monitor the session length on the server, and disconnect there. When you disconnect, send a push notification, which can display a message directly without having to open the app. That is both robust and the intended solution.

Periodically posting a silent notification to wake yourself up will definitely not work because Apple specifically does not want you to do that and they explicitly break it (as they note "silent notifications are not meant as a way to keep your app awake in the background"). It's bad for battery life. This is intended to be solved on your sever, on on the user's device.

Comment: We are using a custom VPN tunnel provider and the problem is that it was written by an extern. If there is any other possible solution than modifying it, I want to try it. Also I don't need the app running in background all the time, the function to check data transfered would take only few ms of computational time. All I need is that high priority for this small task.

Comment: There is no way to launch yourself often and with high priority. You will be throttled very aggressively by Apple.